# Getting ' object is not iterable Error in my code

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I'm getting "Type object is not iterable" error while running this code of my project in EucledianScore's for loop ->j in train_user..This code is for user-user collaborative filtering using the dataset from MovieLens.I've seen many "Type object is not iterable" problem's solution but those are not working for my code.

```
def user_collabo():
def EucledianScore(train_user, test_user):
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    for i in test_user:
        score = 0
        for j in train_user:
            if(int(i[1]) == int(j[1])):
                score= ((float(i[2])-float(j[2]))*(float(i[2])-float(j[2])))
                count= count + 1        
            sum = sum + score
    if(count<4):
        sum = 1000000           
    return(math.sqrt(sum))
data_cols=['user id','movie id','rating','timestamp']
item_cols=['movie id','movie title','release date',
'video release date','IMDb URL','unknown','Action',
'Adventure','Animation','Childrens','Comedy','Crime',
'Documentary','Drama','Fantasy','Film-Noir','Horror',
'Musical','Mystery','Romance ','Sci-Fi','Thriller',
'War' ,'Western']
user_cols = ['user id','age','gender','occupation',
'zip code']
users = pd.read_csv('u.user', sep='|', names=user_cols, encoding='latin-1')
item = pd.read_csv('u.item', sep='|', names=item_cols, encoding='latin-1')
data = pd.read_csv('u.data', sep='\t', names=data_cols, encoding='latin-1')
utrain = (data.sort_values('user id'))[:99832]
print(utrain.tail())
utest = (data.sort_values('user id'))[99833:]
print(utest.head())
utrain = utrain.as_matrix(columns = ['user id', 'movie id', 'rating'])
utest = utest.as_matrix(columns = ['user id', 'movie id', 'rating'])
users_list = []
for i in range(1,943):
    list1 = []
    for j in range(0,len(utrain)):
        if utrain[j][0] == i:
            list1.append(utrain[j])    
        else:
            break
    utrain = utrain[j:]
    users_list.append(list1)      
score_list = []               
for i in range(0,942):
    score_list.append([i+1,EucledianScore(users_list[i], utest)])

score = pd.DataFrame(score_list, columns = ['user id','Eucledian Score'])
score = score.sort_values(by = 'Eucledian Score')
#print(score)
score_matrix = score.as_matrix()
user= int(score_matrix[0][0])
common_list = []
full_list = []
for i in utest:
    for j in users_list[user-1]:
        if(int(i[1])== int(j[1])):
            common_list.append(int(j[1]))
        full_list.append(j[1])

common_list = set(common_list)  
full_list = set(full_list)
recommendation = full_list.difference(common_list)
item_list = (((pd.merge(item,data).sort_values(by = 'movie id')).groupby('movie title')))['movie id', 'movie title', 'rating']
item_list = item_list.mean()
item_list['movie title'] = item_list.index
item_list = item_list.as_matrix()
recommendation_list = []
for i in recommendation:
    recommendation_list.append(item_list[i-1])

recommendation = (pd.DataFrame(recommendation_list,columns = ['movie id','mean rating' ,'movie title'])).sort_values(by = 'mean rating', ascending = False)
print(recommendation[['mean rating','movie title']])
```

user_collabo()

**Output:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-24f9c9703462> in <module>
     71         recommendation = (pd.DataFrame(recommendation_list,columns = ['movie id','mean rating' ,'movie title'])).sort_values(by = 'mean rating', ascending = False)
     72         print(recommendation[['mean rating','movie title']])
---> 73 user_collabo()

<ipython-input-20-24f9c9703462> in user_collabo()
     43         score_list = []
     44         for i in range(0,942):
---> 45                 score_list.append([i+1,EucledianScore(users_list[i], utest)])
     46 
     47         score = pd.DataFrame(score_list, columns = ['user id','Eucledian Score'])

<ipython-input-20-24f9c9703462> in EucledianScore(train_users, test_user)
      5                 for i in test_user:
      6                         score = 0
----> 7                         for j in train_users:
      8                                 if(int(i[1]) == int(j[1])):
      9                                         score= ((float(i[2])-float(j[2]))*(float(i[2])-float(j[2])))

TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from this line:

```
users_list.append(list)
```

This appends the python builtin type `list`. I think you meant `users_list.append(list1)`. This will build up `users_list` into a list of lists.